# Absurdly large area estimates when extracting landcover area for individual polygons (CORINE Data)

Tags: area, shape-area, value-extraction

I want to extract area under different CORINE classes as a part of my master's thesis. I am facing problems with the area estimates that QGIS calculates for landcover classes from the CORINE dataset for individual polygons.

A little bit about the data:
I have a GeoPackage of polygons drawn for individual waterbodies. I used this file to create buffers around the individual polygons of 200m, 400m, 800m, and 1000m.

The error:
'AREA_CALC" column is a new field I created to include 'pond area' + 'buffer area' with the formula "$area", in the attribute table. The resulting area estimates are very large, more the the an order of 10^3 in comparison to the pond area without the buffers (see the column "AREA_CALC"(buffer =250m) versus the "area" column, which contains area values for the waterbodies without the buffers).

I don't understand the reason for this error and therefore am unable to resolve it. I have tried consulting a few colleagues, sadly to no avail. I will happily share any more data that may be required.

Additional information:
The steps I used for extracting area under each land class are as follows:

1. Creating a reprojected layer of the CORINE values to match the project coordinates. Adding an "Object id" (= $id) and "Object area" ($area) column in this layer.
   1a. While exporting the features, I selected "Extent" --> From layer: "Buffer 'x' metres".
2. Then I created a 'level' column with the following formula:

```
 WHEN 'code18' >=100 AND 'code18' <200 THEN 1
 WHEN 'code18' >=200 AND 'code18' <300 THEN 2
 WHEN 'code18' >=300 AND 'code18' <400 THEN 3
 WHEN 'code18' >=400 AND 'code18' <500 THEN 4
 WHEN 'code18' >500 THEN 5
END
```

3. Then I used the 'Dissolve' tool to dissolve from the 'level' column (Input layer= CORINE)
4. Then I intersected the dissolved layer with the layer containing the buffer polygons.
5. For the intersected layer, I created a column called "Class Area" (= $area) to generate the amount of area for each land cover class.
6. Lastly, from the intersected layer, I calculated the "%area under a landcover class" as: 'Class Area/Area' (step 1). ]